# SwiftUI iPad shortcuts bar hides tabBar

Tags: swift, ipad, swiftui, keyboard

I have a (SwiftUI) app for iOS with a tab bar:
[image]

If the user want to copy text from the main view the shortcuts bar jumps over the tab bar and hides the bar:
[image]

How can a disable the shortcuts bar in my app? I don't want the user to disable it in the iPhone settings.
Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe there is a key for the info.plist but I can't find any hint. something similar to statusBar hide?! --> <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
<true/>
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
<false/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem with this two lines of code:

textField.inputAssistantItem.leadingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()
textField.inputAssistantItem.trailingBarButtonGroups.removeAll()